# wascana eclipse simple C code Launch failed no binaries found

Tags: c, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse CDT. I did some online search but I got lost. I installed MinGW (works fine with command window), then I installed Eclipse Helios wascana. I did add path/enviroment to Properties->C/C++ build -> enviroment (C:\MinGW\bin)
Eclipse underlines 
    `#include <stdlib.h>` 
        #include 
        #include
unresolved inclusion. I guess I did not link it to MinGW libraries.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I did the following: Properties->C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor then I chose MinGw GCC as the current toolchain. It looks like it works now. Give it a show

Answer (score 1):

Go to:-  properties> C/C++ Build> Tool Chain Editor>

then, select :-

```
  Current Tool chain as --> Cygwin GCC
```

and,

```
  Current builder as --> CDT Internal Builder
```

it worked for me. hope it will work for u and others as well!! :)

EDit : for linux users

Answer (score 0):

I got this error even when the compiler was certanly ok, so only build/rebuild (sometimes) and starting new project could help. May be it's not your case, but Eclipse "loves" this error so much, that's wat i found out about it